# How can I add identity for primary key column in already existing table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I know how I can create as new column with primary key and identity, but I wanted to do different like...

How can I add identity for a primary key column in already existing table in SQL Server?

I did already by using GUI in SQL Server, but that is not working. You can see this in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You cannot **add** an `identity` specification to an existing column. You need to create a **new column** and make it `identity`

Answer (score 0):

Try switch operator

```
 CREATE TABLE Test
  (
    id int not null primary key,
    name varchar(10)
  );

  INSERT INTO Test VALUES (1,'John');
  INSERT INTO Test VALUES (2,'Peter');

  CREATE TABLE Test2
  (
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    name varchar(10)
  );

  ALTER TABLE Test SWITCH TO Test2;

 DROP TABLE Test;

 EXEC sp_rename 'Test2','Test';
```

Comment: Are you sure that SQL Server has `SWITCH` keyword?